# Linux duplicate and extra processes in ps output

Tags: linux, memory, java, docker, rss

I am using the Linux `ps` command to monitor the RSS size of the processes from inside a Docker container.  If the total RSS goes above a threshold, then I fail the tests and start looking for memory regressions.

Here is the entire `ps` output from inside a Docker container.

```
 PID %CPU      RSS Threads COMMAND
   1  0.0     2616       1 sh /test/Build/unittest.sh
   7  3.3    44240       1   /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 ...
  17  1.5    10824       1   /usr/bin/fluxbox
 357  690  6292244     324   java -server -Xmx2g ...
 490  0.4     7852       1     /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/dstat ...
 491  0.7     7812       1     /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/dstat ...
1331  0.0     3040       1     /usr/bin/ps -AHww --format ...
1332  0.0      380       1     /usr/bin/ls --all ...
1333  0.0  6292248       1     [NDR-347]
```

The Java process (pid: 357) creates short-lived child processes.  In the above output, you can see 2 dstat Python processes, ps, ls and [NDR-347]".  These were all created by the Java process.

Sometimes, I see a duplicate child process (i.e. same command) but different process ID (not shown).  Why do I see a duplicate child process?  I figure this is some sort of Linux or Docker artifact.  What is that artifact?

I have been monitoring `ps` output for over a year now.  For the first time, I see an extra process "[NDR-347]" (pid: 1333) with almost the same RSS.  The Java process (pid: 357) names the threads "NDR-#" so I find it strange that the command of a child process would be the name of a thread from the Java process.  The extra process doubles the RSS and triggers a problem.  The problem is not reproducible.  This suggests to me that pid 1333 is very short-lived and is not caught by `ps`.  The total RSS is 12.07 GB and without the extra process it is 6.07 GB.  What is this extra process?  Why does it have such a huge RSS?

Edit: The exact `ps` command is...

```
ps -Ahww --format pid,%cpu,rss:8,nlwp=Threads,command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a java process that runs other programs.

Like any other process that wants to run another program, the first step is to `fork`. This forked process inherits the memory map of the parent. This memory is shared, so it doesn't really use additional RAM.

The next step after `fork` is to `execve` the new process. The `execve` releases all memory and maps the memory from the new program.

Normally the `execve` follows very soon after the `fork`, so it is unlikely that you catch a process in this state, but occasionally it will happen.

In your particular case, if you know that the forked Java processes contain the name `NDR-`, then you should just ignore these processes.

Comment: Thanks!  I already made the code changes to ignore this process.  On a heavily loaded machine, the time between `fork` and `execve` may be prolonged so that might be when I am more likely to see this.